# Interaction between ruby and js in rails - interesting moment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So, there is method in conroller:

```
 def create
    email=params[:email]
    email=email.downcase
    user = User.find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])&& user.confirmed
      if session[:was_going]
      @url=session[:was_going]
      session[:was_going]=nil
      end
      @status=true
      cookies[:auth_token] = {:value => user.auth_token, :expires => Time.now + 30.days }
    elsif user && !user.confirmed
      @status=false
      @unconfirmed=true
    else
      #@unconfirmed=false  commented line
      @status=false
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{[@status, @url]}
    end
  end
```

It responds to format.js. On any case of authentication process I have boolean variable, which I pass to JS - @status (authenticated or not), @unconfirmed - special message, and just invalid input (if both @status and @unconfirmed are false). Pay attention to commented line.

Here is js template:

```
if(<%=@status %>) {
    window.location.replace("<%= @url %>")

}
else {
    if (<%=@unconfirmed %>) {
        $('.sign_in').replaceWith("<%= j render :file=> 'signs/index.html.erb' %>")
        $('.signs_form').prepend("<div id='errors_of_sign'> Check your mailbox on <br /> confirmation letter </div> ")
        $('.signs_form').css({"margin-top":"30px"})
        $('.facebook_sign').css({"margin-top":"80px"})
        $('.sign_in').fadeIn('fast')

       }
    else{
        $('.sign_in').replaceWith("<%= j render :file=> 'signs/index.html.erb' %>")
        $('.signs_form').prepend("<div id='errors_of_sign'> Email or password are incorrect </div> ")
        $('.signs_form').css({"margin-top":"30px"})
        $('.facebook_sign').css({"margin-top":"80px"})
        $('.sign_in').fadeIn('fast')

    }
}
```

And there was trouble - when there was no commented line, the code for `else` statement didn't work at all.
Then I added that line, and now everything works.

Can you please explain this behaviour of JS? I mean, if there is no variable @unconfirmed, than ruby should return nil, which equal to false in boolean functions of any language I know, including JS.

Comment: It seems like you don't pass `@unconfirmed` to `format.js`? I admit I don't know much about ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about ruby that it will return nil , if not declared but JS doesn't know what nil is .
Js knows 'true' or 'false'

'nil' is not defined in JS.

Try it yourself on console

Comment: You mean that rails'es escape javascript doesn't interpretate 'nil' as 'null' in output?

Comment: where did you escaped javascript ?